# Process vs Worker vs Thread vs Task vs Pool in Node.js

Tags: node.js

What is Process, Worker, Thread, Task, Pool in Node.js from a programmer point of view?

I went through a lot of material, but difficult to understand quickly for a beginner programmer. Here is a quick summary

Answer (score 11):

A **Node.js** `process` is created when run a Node.js program like `node app.js` (or the child process created through `child_process` or `cluster` modules). Each process will have its own memory and resources

**Worker** is a Node.js built-in module which takes your module (.js) as an input and creates `worker` object, inside a `process`, that executes asynchronously.

```
//app.js
//TODO add modules
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads');

//TODO wrap the below code into your code

const worker = new Worker('./task_processor.js');
const workerMaxLifetime = 10000;

//Send message to worker
worker.postMessage('Message to thread');
//Receive message from worker
worker.on('message', (message) => { console.log(' App:', message); });
//Terminate worker
setTimeout(() => { worker.terminate(); }, workerMaxLifetime);
```

**Task** is your module (.js) where you write the code to run as a Thread. Actually, we should call it 'Task Processor'

```
//task_processor.js
//TODO add modules
const { parentPort } = require('worker_threads');
//TODO wrap the below code into your code

//Receive message from App
parentPort.on('message', (task_input) => {
  //Send message to App
  parentPort.postMessage(task_input.a + task_input.b);
});
```

**Thread** is nothing but the worker in execution.

**Pool** is a wrapper .js file which create/terminate worker objects and facilitates communication between App and worker. Worker pool is not mandatory though most real world scenarios implements pools where worker thread concept is implemented. [Example](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/async_hooks.html#async-resource-worker-pool)

**Node.js module** is a .js file

**App:** The main(or default) thread in a `process` is also referred as App

**Process vs Worker:** Each `process` will have its own memory and resources, whereas `worker` uses the same memory and resources of the process from which it is created.